# Lens Laws: what are they trying to tell me?

Tags: functional-programming, lenses

I've seen various versions of the Lens Laws. Not sure if they're all intended to be equivalent, so for definiteness I'll use the version on StackOverflow against tag `Lenses` [Edward Kmett ~ 5 years ago]

(I'm asking because I want more of a handle on bi-directional programming.)

Using `a` as a structure, `b` as a component/value in the structure:

1. `get (set b a) = b`

Ok. What you get is what you've put. Seems essential for anything calling itself a data structure/container. I might have a slight q: where did the initial `a` come from? Could I go directly `get a`? What would that mean?

2. `get (set b' (set b a)) = b'`

?I believe this is intended to be telling me: what you get is what you last put (and anything you put before is lost forever). But it doesn't actually say that. It doesn't (for example) exclude that the lens is a stack-within-`a` -- i.e. `get` behaves like pop. So if I do a second `get` it might return the earlier `b`. IOW it needs to say: once you've `set b' (whatever-a)`, `get` will always return `b'` *ad infinitum*.

This is law is sometimes written in the form: `set b' (set b a) = set b' a`. But I don't like that at all, which brings me to:

3. `set (get a) a = a`

Putting what you've already got does nothing. (That seems a barely interesting thing to say: doesn't it follow from Law 1?) But an equality test on the structure is breaking the abstraction. We (as clients of the structure) don't care how the structure organises itself internally. Our interface is in terms of the methods `get`, `set`. Putting what you've already got might change the structure's value for all we care -- just as long as a `get` returns that value we put.

If there's something crucial about the value/contents of `set (get a) a`, can't that be expressed in terms of `get`/`set`? And if it can't, why do we care?

---

All these laws are in terms of a single lens. So they would hold if the structure was merely a single 'slot' -- which seems a lot of machinery for something aka a 'variable'.

What does seem to be missing is anything about how you can combine distinct lenses to work through a more complex structure. Such that the structure allows each lens to work orthogonally.  I believe there's a van Laarhoven law:

`-- I need two lenses, so I'll use get', set' as well as get, set
 get' (set b (set' b' a)) = b'`

Do I not need a law like that? Please explain.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used this formalism before, so it might show in my answer.

1. This is a mathematical law. It doesn't matter where `a` comes from, as long as it satisfies the relevant mathematical requirements. In programming, you could define it in your code, load it from a file, parse it from network call, build it recursively; whatever.
2. It can't say that. `get` doesn't return a new structure, only the value; and the whole point of lenses is to create a framework for *immutable, side-effect-free* structures. Let `a'` be `(set b' (set b a))`; `get a'` will return `b'` each and every time, because `a'` can't change, and `get` is pure function; there is no place for state to be stored. Your "`get` will always return `b'` *ad infinitum*" is assumed to *always* be true in for a pure function, there is no need for a further stipulation. To implement a stack, you need one of two things: either for it to be mutable, side-effectful (so that `get a == get a` is not necessarily true), or the manipulation functions need to return the new stack - both `put` and `get`.
3. <strike>I failed to construct a counterexample for this, probably because it is intuitively so strong.</strike> Here is a very tenuous counterexample: Let `get a (Container b _) = b`, `set b (Container b c) = Container b (c + 1)`, `set b (Container b' _) = Container b 0`. Furthermore, let `a = Container b' 0` and `b != b'`. First law: `get (set b a) = get (Container b 0) = b` - OK. Second law: `get (set b' (set b a)) = get (set b' (Container b 0)) = get (Container b' 0) = b'` - OK. However, `set (get a) a = set (get (Container b' 0)) (Container b' 0) = set b' (Container b') = Container b' 1 != a` - not OK. Thus, it does not follow from the first law. Without this, you cannot test two structures for equality, and would instead need to iterate each accessor to prove that the two structures are equal (and as a JavaScript programmer, let me tell you: not having object identity function is *really awkward*).
4. You do. Imagine this: `set b a = Container b`, `get (Container b) = b`. First law: `get (set b a) = get (Container b) = b` - OK. Second law: `get (set b' (set b a)) = get (set b' (Container b)) = get (Container b') = b'` - OK; Third law: let `a == Container b`: `set (get a) a = set (get (Container b)) a = set b a = Container b = a` - OK. All three laws are satisfied with this very simple (and kind of obviously wrong) definition. Now let's add `set' b a = Container' b`, `get' (Container' b) = b`), and see what happens: `get' (set b (set' b' a)) = get' (set b (Container' b')) = get' (Container b)`... and this can't get evaluated. Oopsie. Or, imagine this: `set b a = Container b 0`, `get (Container b _) = b`, `set' b a = Container b 1`, `get' (Container b _) = b`. In this case, `get' (set b (set' b' a)) = get' (set b (Container b' 1)) = get' (Container b 0) = b` - not OK. This law guarantees that the values set by `set'` will be preserved in the structure even if we apply `set` (something that is definitely not the case in this example).

Comment: Wow @Amadan, thanks for the quick & comprehensive answer. This is going to get chunky, so I'll put up separate comments for each of your points.      1. "It doesn't matter where `a` comes from." Ok that's what I expected. So the law could be `get (set b <don't care>) = b`

Comment: 2. " /immutable, side-effect-free/ structures ... pure function" Ok, also what I expected. So the law could be `get (set b' (<don't care>)) = b'`. IOW same as Law 1 (modulo alpha renaming).

Comment: 3. "as a JavaScript programmer, " You poor sausage. "let me tell you: not having object identity function is really awkward" Another crime on the charge sheet for Javascript, then. I'm a functional programmer. I don't want object identity/pointer equality. I'm a Haskell programmer so (hooray) I can't do that. You told me (2.) "pure function" so I only get Leibniz equality -- which I test with `get`. So the law could be `get (set (get a) <don't care>) = get a`. And since `get a` is a "pure function"/referentially transparent, that looks ever-so like Law 1 again.

Comment: I misspoke; there is object *identity* function, but not object *equality* function. Object *identity* function is most often useless; but sometimes it is really useful to test whether objects have the same keys with same values.

Comment: 3. (cont) I don't care what goes on inside the structure. If it's keeping a counter, I'm never allowed to `get` that. (Or if I am, that's two distinct lenses into the same structure. So that's covered by your point 4.)

Comment: Take it up with the guys proposing the laws. I'm just interpreting what they are :P

Comment: Thanks @Amadan, I'm hoping StackOverflow is the place to ask "the guys proposing the laws". One of the earliest answers re Lens is a long, complex description from EKmett.

Comment: Re the put-this-put-that-get-this absent law (point 4) I guess one of the difficulties is nested structures -- which are supposed to be a forté. If I have two distinct lenses, of which one looks inside the other, my putative van Laarhoven law won't hold. So then you need a story addressing orthogonal vs overlapping lenses (which is exactly the problem for bi-directional programming).  I vaguely remember watching a video/lecture from EKmett in which he just hand-waved it away.

Answer (score 0):

If you're coming at this with expectations of Bidirectional Programming, I'm not surprised you're puzzled, AntC.

The FAQ page Resources [1] cites Pierce and Voigtländer (both of whom state similar laws); but really they're working with a quite different semantics. For example the Pierce et al 2005 paper:

> The *get* component of a lens corresponds exactly to a view definition. In order to support a compositional approach, we take the perspective that a view state is an entire database (rather than just a single relation, as in many treatments of views).

So these are 'views' in the database sense (and that leads to the punning on terms from optics). There's always a 'base' schema definition (data structure) to/from which the lenses transform the view. Both Pierce and Voigtländer are trying to manage the 'size and shape' of data structures, to preserve transformations between them. Then no wonder they're thinking that the 'base' is the chief holder of content, and the lenses merely mechanisms to look through.

With functional references, there's no such difficulty. Lenses focus on 'slots' in a single data structure. And the structure is treated as abstract.

If the functional references approach wants to lay down laws in terms of 'slots', and specifically treat what Pierce calls *oblivious* lenses, it has to take on the semantics for the parts of the structure outside the lens. What the Voigtländer et al 2012 paper deals with using the *res* (residue) function; or prior work on database views [Bancilhon & Spyratos 1981] calls the "complement".

The `set` function in the laws quoted in the O.P. is *oblivious* in the sense it ignores the current content of the 'slot' and overwrites it. Lenses aren't necessarily like that. Recent treatments use an `upd` function (with an additional parameter `f` for the update to apply to the current value). Note

```
get (upd f a) = f (get a).
get (set b a) = b = get (upd (const b) a).   (Law 1)
```

Except that not all lens `upd` operations observe those equivalences. There is, for example, the neat trick of a lens that `get`s the `day` slot from a date; but whose `upd (+ 1)` increments the whole date. `getDay (updDay (+ 1) (Date {year = 2017, month = 2, day = 28}) )` returns `1`, not `29`.

To the specific questions in the O.P.

1. "slight q": the initial `a` comes from a `create` function [Voigtländer]
   and there's a bunch of `create`/`get` laws.

   - Or is already in the 'base' schema [Pierce].
2. @Amadan's answer is right on the money. `get` and `set` are pure functions.

   - `get` must return whatever was last `set`, by Law 1. So Law 2 seems pointless.
3. Is important to state for Pierce and Voigtländer because they regard the 'base' as critical.

   - For functional references (if the data structure is supposed to be held abstract),
   - stating this law is breaking the abstraction.
   - It is also failing to state the behaviour for other Lenses into the structure,
     if `set` **changes** the value -- which is surely what  Lens user wants to understand.
   - So again seems pointless.
   - Note neither Pierce's nor Voigtländer's approaches expect more than one Lens.

---

If two Lenses focus on independent slots within a structure, both of these hold:

```
-- continuing to use get'/set' as well as get/set
 ∀ b b' . get' (set b (set' b' a)) = b'     -- law for set' inside set
 ∀ b' b . get (set' b' (set b a)) = b       -- law for set inside set'
```

If two Lenses interfere/overlap, neither equation holds (in general for all values in the domain of `set`, `set'`).

So to take the 'worst' but still plausible case from above of `getDay`/`updDay`focussing inside `getDate`/`setDate`: 
Law 1 holds for `getDate`/`setDate`; but `updDay` doesn't behave like a version of `set`.
Laws 2 & 3 hold (but seem pointless).

There's no laws we can usefully write about their interaction.
I guess the best we could do is segregate the Lenses that focus inside the same structure
 into groupings that do/don't mutually interfere.

Overall I don't think the Lens Laws are much help in understanding Lenses as they are used nowadays.

[1] https://github.com/ekmett/lens/wiki/FAQ#lens-resources